# How to translate the Expr(Const number) in Z3 to be an object in MPQ/MPFR

Tags: interface, ocaml, z3, translate, mpfr

When I use the **Z3-opt**(**Ocaml** version) to solve some planning problem, and I get a result from Z3 like this:

(+ (/ 31.0 10.0) (* (to_real (- 1)) ***epsilon***))

And this result is of type of Z3.Expr. I want to know how to translate this result(of Z3.Expr) to anther common data-type object(for example, MPQ/MPFR).

Does the Z3-opt(Ocaml version) provide the **ocaml interface** to this?

Many thanks.

Comment: The result like (+ (/ 31.0 10.0) (* (to_real (- 1)) epsilon)) is to complex. I could not use this in my project. How could I get the rational number it represents?

Comment: Have you already looked through [this file](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/src/api/ml/z3.mli#L473)? I am not sure exactly what you want to do, due to a lack of domain knowledge on my part, but you may want to search for functions that take `Expr.expr` as argument, and see if any match your needs.

Comment: I have tried several interfaces in the file [like](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/src/api/ml/z3.mli).
But it seems to fail to work.
The expr of string (+ (/ 31.0 10.0) (* (to_real (- 1)) epsilon)) could be translated to a float-point number like 3.0999...5. Also it could be truncated to be rational number(like MPQ). But how could I handle this with the ocaml interface provided by Z3-opt?
Thanks.

Comment: If you were using a Z3 binding to a different language, how would you do it? Perhaps we can map it to OCaml, or do you already know that the corresponding functions are missing?

Comment: The Z3 provides the ocaml interface. And Thanks NikolajBjorner. I have found the answer from here https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues/265#event-448255510

Comment: Glad you have it sorted out now. And, I understand Z3 provides the OCaml interface. My suggestion was to take Z3's C++ interface (for example, if you are familiar with C++), figure out how to do it there, and then see how to do the same thing in the OCaml interface. Anyway, enjoy :)

Comment: Hi, antron, thanks for your reply. :)